# How to begin my journey into simulating light-matter interactions?

Tags: optics, simulations, quantum-optics

I am interested in simulating how light interacts with matter. For example, I want to create a 3D heatmap describing how light might scatter in some heterogenous material. But the more I dig into this subject, the more overwhelming it feels. For example, there are so many different ways light can interact with matter:

- Transmission
- Reflection
- Refraction
- Diffraction
- Scattering
- Absorption
- Stimulated photo-emission
- Polarization

Then the next challenge is figuring out how a specific wavelength of light actually interacts with a specific material. So I need some kind of database that has this information. I am unsure where this can be found or if this even exists. And assuming I did find this database, which simulation software should I use to actually build this?

I am trying to understand where I can find resources to actually simulate light-matter interactions and what people do in this field to achieve this task?

Comment: Usually when people simulate light matter interaction, they have a specific scenario in mind. For example, the transmission, reflection, and refraction phenomena would only appear at the interfaces. So that can be neglected if you are interested in phenomena inside the material. Then you gear the simulation to focus on the aspects that you want to study.